# How to use Rails console with ENV config for S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using iTerm 2 on a MacBook. I can't get my rails console to accept ENV variables for manipulating objects that have attachments in my S3 bucket. For starting the server this works fine:

`AWS_REGION=us-west-2 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX S3_BUCKET_NAME=blabla-bucket rails server`

But when I try the same thing for the console:

`AWS_REGION=us-west-2 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX S3_BUCKET_NAME=blabla-bucket rails console`

I get this error when I try to destroy a record with an S3 attachment/upload:

`Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError: missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']`

Answer (score 0):

why not use **[dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)** or **[figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)** gem.